# How to wait for something NOT to happen in Testing Library?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I want to assert on a condition which I know will not be true immediately, but might be true after an async action, in which the test should fail.

Say I'm testing this counter component:

```js
function Counter() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
  function decrement() {
    if (value >= 0) { // <- off by one bug
      someAsyncAction().then(() => setValue(value - 1));
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      Value is {value}
      <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I can write this test to check that the value should not go below zero:

```js
const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Decrement" });
expect(screen.getByText("Value is 1")).toBeInTheDocument();

userEvent.click(button);
expect(await screen.findByText("Value is 0")).toBeInTheDocument();

userEvent.click(button);
// !!! wrong !!!
expect(screen.getByText("Value is 0")).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(screen.queryByText("Value is -1")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
// !!! wrong !!!
```

But the last two assertions *will always pass*, even though the component has a bug which means it will asynchronously update to show "Value is -1".

What is the recommended way to deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 14):

The best I've come up with is:

```js
await expect(
  screen.findByText("Value is -1", {}, { timeout: 100 })
).rejects.toThrow();
```

This tries to find the text, waits for the timeout (reduced from the default 1 second to 100ms to speed up the tests) then rejects which is caught by `expect`. If the text *is* present then the `findByText` call will resolve so the `expect` will reject and the test will fail (don't forget to `await` the `expect`).

This pattern can be extended to other assertions using `waitFor`:

```js
await expect(
  waitFor(
    () => { expect(screen.getByRole('input')).toHaveValue(-1); },
    { timeout: 100 }
  )
).rejects.toThrow();
```

While this works, it's a bit complicated, especially the `waitFor` form. I feel this can still be improved so please chip in if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! I had a lot of trouble figuring this out. I extrapolated your text version to a helper: https://gist.github.com/sirbrillig/330cb59d4d6d788174fbb294edf09599

Comment: If it's helpful to anyone, I updated my Gist linked above to include a Jest custom matcher.

Answer (score 5):

Taking the concepts put forth in [Tamlyn's excellent self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68318058/6831341), I've extrapolated this into a utility called `verifyNeverOccurs` that has the same signature as [Testing Library's `waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) but that only fails if the callback assertion you send it ever passes:

```js
import { waitFor, waitForOptions } from '@testing-library/react';

/**
 * Inverse of RTL's `waitFor`; used to verify that a thing does *not* occur. 
 * Useful for situations in which verifying that some effect did occur would
 * require using `await waitFor()` and you need to test that the effect does
 * not occur. Like `waitFor`, it must be `await`ed.
 * @param {function} negativeAssertionFn - a callback function that expects a thing you do _not_ expect will occur
 * @param {Object} options - options object with same shape as `waitFor`'s options argument (ultimately just passed through to `waitFor`)
 * @return {void}
 */

const verifyNeverOccurs = async (negativeAssertionFn: () => unknown, options?: waitForOptions) => {
  await expect(
    waitFor(negativeAssertionFn, options),
  ).rejects.toThrow();
};

export default verifyNeverOccurs;
```

(This is in TypeScript but you could always strip out the types if you wanted it in vanilla JS).

An example usage:

```js
// fails if `element` ever contains the text "oh no"
verifyNeverOccurs(() => expect(element).toHaveTextContent('oh no'));
```